# Android dependency compileOnly/provided which is not supported

Tags: android, react-native

```
> Task :app:preReleaseBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preReleaseBuild'.
> Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base-license:12.0.1' is set to compileOnly/provided which is not supported
```

Below is my project level gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "11.8.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native-background-geolocation-android/android/libs"
        }
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native-background-fetch/android/libs"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 26
                buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
            }
        }
    }
}
subprojects {
  project.configurations.all {
     resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
              && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
           details.useVersion "26.1.0"
        }
     }
  }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

> Module level gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
// apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.app"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "3.0.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-restart')
    implementation project(':react-native-google-api-availability-bridge')
    implementation project(':react-native-background-job')
    implementation project(':react-native-system-setting')
    implementation project(':bugsnag-react-native')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-resizer')
    implementation project(':react-native-onesignal')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-sound')
    implementation project(':react-native-fs')
    implementation project(':react-native-signature-capture')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-background-timer')
    implementation project(':react-native-background-fetch')
    implementation project(':react-native-background-geolocation-android')
    implementation project(':react-native-camera')
    implementation project(':react-native-localization')
    implementation project(':lottie-react-native')
    implementation project(':react-native-geocoder')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

I'm not from native background so I patched here and there along the way and was working fine all this while but not until today

Comment: Your problem lies in a different `build.gradle` file than the one that you are showing. Look for one in your module's directory.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Updated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmmmm... your dependencies does not list that one, and you're using `implementation`. You might need to hunt through all those `project()` dependencies and see if any of them have the offending line.

Comment: @CommonsWare: And the keyword to use is `provided`? I've searched thru `node_modules` and didnt find any of it

Comment: Either that or `compileOnly`, based on that error message.